# How do I log into another Battle.net account in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

I can't find a "log out" option in-game—how can I switch accounts? Is there some feature to check that will make this easier for me to switch next time?

Comment: AFAIK the only way is to switch in the launcher. No ingame account switching possible.

Comment: I misunderstood the "in the future" part. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blizzard recently introduced the Battle.net launcher. This means you cannot switch accounts in any of the blizzard games by simply clicking a "logout" button in-game.

You basically have to Leave the game completely and then you have to **switch accounts in the Battle.net Launcher.**

Comment: You don't have to use the launcher to launch Blizzard games.  Its possible to manually log into your account.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect with an other account following these steps :

- Go to the main menu (the one where you select your character)
- Hit the escape key to show the menu
- Click on "Disconnect" button

You will be back on the login screen, where you can connect with another account.

Comment: I don't have a "Disconnect" there, just "Exit Diablo"

Comment: That's strange, I had the button when playing on my friend's computer yesterday. I'll check if he was using the Battle.Net launcher or not.

Comment: Whilst in-game, you can force a disconnect and the game will kick you back to the log-in screen. Easy to do, but far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can disconnect from internet while in-game, you will get a message that you are disconnected and when you press the button to proceed you will be dropped to the login screen, where you can change your login.

Comment: Or, just disconnect while launching the game.